# Two forms submit button stay beside each other

Tags: html, css

```
<form class="listing_form" action="{% url 'listing' listing.id  %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place Bid">
</form>
<form class="listing_form_close" action="{% url 'close' listing.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if listing.listedBy.username == request.user.username %}
            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Close Bid">
            {% endif %}
</form>
```

In this code, two submit buttons are stays vertically.

[image]

I need styling same below:

[image]

As I have tried:

```
.listing_form [type="submit"] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline;
  }
  .listing_form_close [type="submit"] {
    display: inline;
  }
```

In my css code, but not works!

Appreciated.

Comment: Are those template placeholders adding any markup?  Can you update the question to demonstrate the DOM structure being used at runtime to create a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  *As a guess*, your styling specifically targets the buttons, but what about the *forms*?  If those are block display then they take up the full width.

Comment: @David, I have succeed using what you mentioned. Styling forms against buttons. TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your CSS code is, that you add `display: inline` to the `input` element, which is inside a `form` element. In this case, all buttons of the type submit inside a form would be inline.

What you actually want to do is to add the `display: inline` attribute to your `form`. So that the two forms which including the buttons are next to each other.

```css
.listing_form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form class="listing_form" action="URL" method="post">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place Bid">
</form>
<form class="listing_form" action="URL" method="post">
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Close Bid">
</form>
```

*Note: I changed the form class of the second form from `listing_form_close` to `listing_form`.*

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, you have incorrectly specified the CSS-selector for buttons.

You're CSS-selectors have spaces between class name `.listing_form` and attribute selector `[type="submit"]`, CSS understands that like `.listing_form` is a parent `[type="submit"]` element.

Also, I recommend the use `display: incline-block`

```
.listing_form[type="submit"] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.listing_form_close[type="submit"] {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Here is more information about CSS-selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Good luck!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators Sayis: The " " (space) combinator selects nodes that are descendants of the first element. Your answer is false. Please correct.